# tomcat6.0 with eclipse 3.4 in windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse

Tomcat 6.0 was installed sucessfully and also getting web page tomcat starter but the prob is in Eclipse: I can see server in windows-preferences-(server option i can't see)

Comment: If you cannot see `Tomcat 6` server on (`File`->`New`->`Server`->`Apache`) then upgrade your Eclipse. I don't think Eclipse bundled Tomcat 6 on Eclipse 3.4 (when it was released).

Answer (score 1):

you would need to add it from your server window

window -> show view -> window

right click on the window -> new -> server

[image]

Then point it to your tomcat 6 installation